# Why can I not write data on the array?

Tags: c++, openmp

I'm using openmp in my project. I have trouble with my code because I can not write data on a 2-dimensional array. I abstract the algorithm and show the simple program as follows:

```
#include <omp.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int i,tmp;
    int cnt[2]={0};
    int reg[2][5000]={0};
    omp_set_num_threads(32); 
    #pragma omp parallel for private(i,tmp) shared(reg, cnt)

    for(i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 1)
        {
            #pragma omp atomic read
            tmp=cnt[1];

            if(tmp < 5000)
            {
                #pragma omp atomic write
                reg[1][tmp]=i;
                #pragma omp atomic
                cnt[1]++;
            }
            
        }
        else{
            #pragma omp atomic read
            tmp=cnt[0];
            if(tmp<5000)
            {
                #pragma omp atomic write
                reg[0][tmp]=i;
                #pragma omp atomic
                cnt[0]++;
            }
            
        }
    }
    printf("%d\t%d\n", cnt[0], cnt[1]);
    for(i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t%d\n", reg[0][i], reg[1][i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

reg[0] should contain only even number and reg[1] should contain only odd number. But in my result, a lot of positions in reg are zero. I suspect that it does not write the data into 'reg'. How can I correct the code?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. In particular, your question misses your actual observations. All you say is "I can not write", which is an interpretation. What happened, what did you expect to happen?

Comment: Does it work without the omp pragmas?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 0):

The result of having all elements of `reg` being populated relies on the sequential execution of:

```
tmp=cnt[1];
[...]
cnt[1]++;
```

However, the atomic operations do not enforce this - there may be multiple `tmp` getting assigned the same value, while sometimes multiple increments are happening in between reading `tmp`. Therefore not all elements of `reg` will be populated.

Abstractly, you can fix this by adding a `#pragma omp critical` section around this region such that it will not be interrupted by anyone else reading or incrementing `cnt[i]`. However, that comes at a steep performance cost and my not be ideal for your actual use case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is a good solution while critical will slow down the speed. Do you have other solutions?